# How make two or more title bars of the Main Activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, title

I want to put two bars in one activity. First I want to put a TextView control switch and the second on a ListView control switch. How to do that? I tried to adjust the main title bar, but I also have the other. I put the two style files, the first containing the controls TextView, ImageView and a list, and the second defines the single field list.

main_activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/main" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/maine"
        android:id="@+id/mainee"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/countryFlag"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descCountryFlag"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryRate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by two bars, two icons in the action bar or do you want two action bars?

Comment: Two bars, but no action but a title. Something like here -> https://lh6.ggpht.com/b0po_ulfHx4mpFwTUkTdXsbPDqhnQqlWI9LgL1EwOYlytS6VgyiHnnmWiaSmc3wCi_8=h900-rw. On one of these strips is the title of the application, and on the second date of the last update. Just to between the two bands can put their own control such as a TextView.